# props.items (Object) is possibly undefined after return early condition

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I've seen a few similar questions but none had the same issue.

I am being confused around Object that is possibly undefined error from TypeScript.

```
interface Props {
  item?: SomeItem;
}

export const Element = (props: Props) => {
  if (props.item === undefined) {
    return null;
  }

  const offer = offers.find((offer) => offer.id === props.item.offer_id);

  return <div>{props.item.getPayoutPlaceholder()}</div>; 
};
```

The error is

> TS18048: 'props.item' is possibly 'undefined'.
> const offer = offers.find((offer) => offer.id === this.item.offer_id);

It shows ONLY in the `find` line. The last one (`return`) doesn't suffer from this.

If I assign the `props.item` to a constant and use it, It stops

```
  const item = props.item;
  if (item === undefined) {
    return null;
  }

  const offer = offers.find((offer) => offer.id === item.offer_id);
```

I get that it could change after the `if` by some asynchronous code. But what makes me really confused is the fact that it doesn't show the same error in `return` statement. What could be  the reason for this?

Comment: I think you may remove the conditional `?` in the interface. As for your question, I don't know myself.

Comment: The function you're passing to `offers.find` uses `item`, which is not defined anywhere in the code you showed, instead of `props.item`. Either you need to use `props.item` if that's what you intended, or you need to show us what `item` is.

Comment: @Jimmy oh snap, I misscopied the code. Fixed. The problem still persists of course

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because `props.item.offer_id` is in a callback, and so TS cannot be sure that `props.item` has not changed between the time you check it and the time the callback is called. As you noted, you could get around it by defining a constant variable:

```
const item = props.item;
```

It should also be noted that destructuring also works:

```
export const Element = ({ item }: Props) => {
```

but notice that changing `const` to `let` [makes the original error surface again](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgIilQ3wG4BYAKCuADsYkpN0k4AFHMAZzgG8q4cYAxAB+AFxxaAVxAAjRhUoBfKlTQRaXeBEyZGPALxwA2ryEATSfnxxlAXSVUkAD0iw4GrfACiAGyQQJHo4YwAKME4uSQ4IbgBKUIA+PgE4APhhQNC4SLiuADoskCdKQWBMODDi0MNjaVoLJEw6JAtE-jLBOCIYaShaKWk-PyVBVS60r204XX0oHLmDApbGsLClqETDFM2ii1rjYoKYCABlGCg6AHMw+PixuAB6J+6394-Pr++PgD1-35pNK9fqDAA8FmAADckrxjqcLldaLd4sowU9ITDSHAqMpSEA):

```
let item = props.item;
```

and that's because now TS is not sure that it hasn't changed, like before (since `let` is mutable and can be reassigned).

The usage of `props.item.offer_id` works in the `return` statement because it isn't in any sort of context that can have delayed execution. As an example of this, in the following code, TS is smart enough to see that this function expression will be immediately invoked and thus it must be synchronous:

```
// OK, even though it's in another function
(() => props.item.offer_id)();
```

Anyways, regardless of why TS behaves the way it does here, I suggest you use [destructuring directly from the parameter list](https://tsplay.dev/Nd2MnW). It's clean, widely used, and solves this issue straight away without needing to declare extra constant variables.

Comment: WOW. Excelent, clean answer, really love the note about TS being smart enough :) So for example, find function placing the callback inside setTimeout, right?
Thank you