# Why does TypeScript type narrowing not work in callback functions?

Tags: typescript

**The code below is what's causing the error**

```
function upload(
    url: string,
    files: {
        file: File;
        fieldname: string;
    }[],
    options: {
        onProgress: Function;
        customData?: Record<string, any>;
        method?: string;
    } = {
        onProgress() {},
        method: "POST",
    }
) {
    options.customData &&
        Object.keys(options.customData).forEach(
            (fieldname) =>
                typeof options.customData[fieldname] !== "undefined" &&
                formData.append(fieldname, options.customData[fieldname])
        );
}
```

[TS Playground](https://tsplay.dev/weBxaN)

I'm getting this error; it's typescript specific:

> 'options.customData' is possibly 'undefined'. ts(18048)

`options.customData &&`  should narrow the type according to [narrowing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html), but it doesn't work, if the access is inside a callback function.

Narrowing in the following code works:

```
function upload(
    url: string,
    files: {
        file: File;
        fieldname: string;
    }[],
    options: {
        onProgress: Function;
        customData?: Record<string, any>;
        method?: string;
    } = {
        onProgress() {},
        method: "POST",
    }
) {
    options.customData && options.customData["fieldname"];
}
```

[TS Playground](https://tsplay.dev/WG4MXw)

Comment: yes when I try running the code I'm getting this error 'options.customData' is possibly 'undefined'.ts. from typescript how do I fix it

Comment: Perhaps you should see my [earlier answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75038004/props-items-object-is-possibly-undefined-after-return-early-condition/75075873#75075873) describing why callbacks don't preserve type narrowing and how you can work around it.

Comment: @jackssrt You removed the first link in your edit which contained the first codeblock. While I admit it is misleading that there are two playground links and that they may seem like duplicates, they do indeed lead to different playgrounds. Check that links are different before removing them in the future, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ts does not remember the narrowing in the forEach function call.

See [TypeScript Type Narrowing Error with forEach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63223715/typescript-type-narrowing-error-with-foreach)

Short explanation is, that it does in general not know when the callback is executed, so the narrowing may not be valid any longer.

You can do

```
  const customData = options.customData
  customData
      && Object.keys(customData).forEach(
             (fieldname) => typeof customData[fieldname] !== 'undefined'
              && formData.append(fieldname, customData[fieldname])
         );
```

Comment: When you find a duplicate question with an answer, you shouldn't write duplicate answer. You should vote to close as duplicate.

Comment: @jabaa That is, if you have enough reputation. I believe you can still flag a question as a duplicate if you are under 3K, though.

Comment: @jabaa I am able to mark as duplicate.  I didnt think the linked question was quite the same though...